# SAA Congruence Criterion in Neutral Geometry

Tags: hilbert-spaces, triangles, fake-proofs

What is wrong with the following proof of the SAA congruence criterion?

Consider $\triangle$ABC and $\triangle$DEF. Given $AC\cong DF$, $\angle A \cong \angle D$, and $\angle B \cong \angle E$ it follows that $\angle C \cong \angle F$ since 
\begin{equation} \label*{}
\begin{split}
(\angle C)° & = 180°-(\angle A)°-(\angle B)° \\
 & = 180°-(\angle D)°-(\angle E)° \\
 & = (\angle F)°
\end{split}
\end{equation}

In Neutral geometry, do we not know that the interior angles of a triangle add to 180°? I don't see where this proof uses Euclid's parallel postulate or its results.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the sum of the interior angles of a triangle add to 180° does not hold in Neutral geometry. It is equivalent to Euclid's parallel postulate if you assume the Archimedean axiom.